# To attain drawer navigation menu on the right in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

When i am adding selected code then its showing undefined object (evaluating 'route.routeName').
Navigation drawer is by default on the left. How to attain it on right side ?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import ScreenFirst from "./src/ScreenFirst";
import ScreenTwo from "./src/ScreenTwo";

const DrawerExample = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    ScreenFirst: { screen: ScreenFirst },
    ScreenTwo: { screen: ScreenTwo }
  },
  {
    drawerPosition: "right",
    drawerWidth: 100
  }
);
export default DrawerExample;
```

[image]

Comment: your error and configuration are unrelated. you've probably hitted this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886782/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-route-routename

Answer (score 6):

if you are using navigation 3.x you will need to import these guys

```
import {createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'
```

then try this one:

```
const DrawerExample = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    ScreenFirst: { screen: ScreenFirst },
    ScreenTwo: { screen: ScreenTwo }
  },
  {
    drawerPosition: "right",
    drawerWidth: 100
  }
);

const MyApp = createAppContainer(DrawerExample);
export default MyApp
```

Answer (score 3):

For 6.x

```
  <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"  screenOptions={{drawerPosition:"right"}}
 >
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

For who comes from React Navigation V5. Just call `drawerPosition` like below:

```
<Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="SignIn" drawerPosition="right">
    <Drawer.Screen name="welcome" component={Welcome} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Comment: doesnt work....

Comment: Make sure you are in V5 version and all code like the example above.

Comment: I am using "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.1",

Comment: so @dontdownvoteme, as you can read, my answer is for V5, not V6 so you can't compare. I suggest you read the official documentation.

Comment: I appologize then. Can you help me with adding custom labels to the drawer view? By default when I slide the drawer, it just shows default names of the screens, but I want to show a custom label and icons.

Answer (score 2):

```
import {DrawerActions} from '@react-navigation/native';
```

<Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{ drawerPosition: 'right', }}> <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{ headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'orange', }, headerTintColor: 'black', headerLeft:false, headerRight: () => ( <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}> ), }} /> <Drawer.Screen name="Standings" component={Standings} /> </Drawer.Navigator>

it worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In React Navigation version 5, add the `drawerPosition` prop with value `right` in your Drawer Navigator.

```
<Drawer.Navigator drawerPosition="right">
  <Drawer.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
  <Drawer.Screen name="Article" component={Article} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Read [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#drawerposition) for the official docs.

Comment: try this instead screenOptions={{ drawerPosition: 'right }}