# undefined is not an object (evaluating route.routeName)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

[image]
when update the expo from (16.0.0) to (24.0.0) and react navigation from (git+https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation.git) to (^1.0.0-beta.21) version, this error occured

Comment: Got the exact same issue just yesterday when I installed `react native elements`. Cant figure out how to solve this!!

Comment: everything is ruined, cant move beyond this point!

Comment: spent two days but not find any solution. Finally got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: same here, I spend like 2 days myself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally found out how to solve this, its an **undocumented** DrawerNavigatorConfig:

```
drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
```

Look here:
https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/3148#issuecomment-352778884

Answer (score 0):

remove ^ from package json before react-nativetion package

it should be look like this "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.20"

not "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.20" (^ means you are allowing npm install to the install latest version which is the cause of the problem )

after removing ^ you have to delete your node_module and then Run npm install this will install correct packages for your current project

Answer (score 0):

Simply, **change to**  "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.26"   **from**   "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.20"